# 404 ошибка и 302 редирект

Tags: http-status-code-404, .htaccess

Есть вот такой движок и он возвращает 302 found на  404 ошибку. Нужно сразу чтобы выдавался код 404.

Как поправить это?

[Лего шоп](http://legosp.net/info/nashi-uslugi/)

[Несуществующий линк](http://legosp.net/info/fsdfsdfdfs)

В htaccess такое

```
#errors
RewriteRule 301$ core/core_301.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule 404$ core/core_404.php [L,QSA]

# ErrorDocument 301 http://example.com/301/
ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com/404
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404
```

Очень нужна помощь.

header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

В файле ошибки посылается.

Answer (score 2):

Поправил в самом движке. там стоял rewrite, вот такое было в файле /includes/aux_pages.php:

```
 if (!$p) {
        //not found
        //header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        header("Location: http://".CONF_SHOP_URL."/404/");
        exit;
        }
```

Разработчики тупят.